# MySQL Derived column not recognized as functionally dependent

Tags: mysql, group-by

With the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Example` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `properties` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash` binary(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (unhex(sha(`properties`))) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

the column `hash` is derived from the column `properties`. In the nomenclature in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html), `{properties} -> {hash}`

Also from the docs concerning [handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html), comes the following:

> SQL:1999 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of customers

However, despite this, the following query returns an error (no data is required in the table to reproduce this):

```
SELECT `properties` from `Example` GROUP BY `hash`;
```

The error is

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dispatch.Example.properties' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The error says the column is NOT functionally dependent. This is probably because the query analyzer doesn't assume that the value returned by the `SHA` function is deterministic. Maybe? Is the possibility of a hash collision killing this whole idea?

The hash is considerably less useful if I still have to apply an aggregate function to the `properties` column to populate the result. Is there a way I can assert to MySQL that there is functional dependence?

Failing that, what's the best way to say "just give me the property from any matching row" that doesn't involve comparing `properties` records (which is the point of the hash)? The best I've come up with is `FIRST` in a window function, but that feels janky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the direction of the dependency that I had wrong; with the above example

```
Select `hash` FROM `Example` GROUP BY `properties`
```

works correctly, since `hash` depends on `properties`.

Since in my case `hash` exists solely to be more efficient to index and group by, the above is not an option.

Not mentioned in the [docs for aggregating functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) is the function `ANY_VALUE` that unpredictably returns the value from one of the grouped rows. Since I know the two columns are equivalent, I don't care which row it picks for `properties`.

The resulting working query is:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(`properties`) from `Example` GROUP BY `hash`;
```

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with using a derived column.

Functional dependency works when grouping by the primary key, and some other cases. But in your question, your query does not fit any of the cases. In fact, `properties` is not functionally dependent on `hash` (there could be multiple different values of `properties` that have the same value in `hash`).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

> SQL:1999 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of customers.

You can test your own example table to prove this. Group by the `id` (the table's primary key), and you get no error:

```
mysql> SELECT `properties` from `Example` GROUP BY `id`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Also if you add columns that are not derived columns, you still can't rely on functional dependency, whether they are unique or non-unique.

```
mysql> alter table example 
  add column u int, 
  add unique key (u), 
  add column n int, 
  add key (n);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `properties` from `Example` GROUP BY `u`;
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.Example.properties' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

mysql> SELECT `properties` from `Example` GROUP BY `n`;
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.Example.properties' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

---

Re your comment:

I stand corrected. It's not *only* the primary key, but other cases where MySQL can detect functional dependencies (I have edited the statement near the top of my answer). But not the case you showed in your initial question.

I found a manual page that describes MySQL's support for functional dependencies more fully: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html

Comment: But grouping by the primary key isn't grouping at all.

Comment: Not in this query, but if the query has a join, it could be useful to group by primary key of one table, because the join could match multiple rows from another table.

Comment: Perhaps, but your statement "Functional dependency only works when grouping by the primary key" is incorrect. Note in my answer that grouping by `properties` works, although it is not a primary key - the `hash` column is still a functional dependent because it is derived from `properties`.

Comment: Good point. I have made edits to my answer.